# How to convert a string into date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

I have the following column, `date_period2` in my query which displays date in `yyyy-mm` format but as a string.

```
date_period2
201304
201305
201306
201307
```

How can i convert that to a DATE format so I can use it to get the working days of the specific month. So for example, `201304` would be converted to `04-2013` as a DATE instead of a string.

This is my query which is calculating an expression based on the `date_period2` field and it's not working because it's a string format:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [date_period2]
    ,[amount]
    ,[amount]/(SELECT 20 + COUNT(*) FROM 
        (SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_period2]), 28) AS theDate 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_period2]), 29) 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_period2]), 30) ) AS d 
        WHERE DATEPART(DAY, [date_period2]) > 28 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [date_period2]) % 7 < 5) AS [Weekly Charge]
    FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

The issue is the `amount` is being divided by 20 and not by the working days for the month-year.

Example:

```
date_period2    amount          charge average (amount/total working days of the month)
201304          1750359.95      87517.9975
```

So according to the result above the charge average is supposed to be `1750359.95/22`, but instead it is being divided by 20 giving it the wrong output.

How can I either edit the query or convert the date to ensure the output is done correctly?

Comment: Did you consider storing a date as date?

Comment: Tried to use `CONVERT()` but that didn't do anything.

Comment: If it is a varchar then consider using `substring` to create a parsable date followed by `convert`.

Comment: I was looking up substring as I did it in other programming language but wasn't too sure on how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the string in an unambiguous date format like `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
        SUBSTRING(date_period2,1,4) + '-' 
      + SUBSTRING(date_period2,5,2) + '-01')
```

That will convert `201304` into `2013-04-01` which will convert directly to a `DateTime`.

**EDIT**

Since your source column is *actually* an `integer` column, a cleaner method is:

```
 select CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(6),date_period2)+'01')
```

that will convert `201304` to `"20130401"` whihc is still unambiguous to the datetime parser.

Comment: I get this error: `Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.`

Comment: Is `date_period2` an `int` or a `varchar`?

Comment: I believe it is a varchar. BTW I upvoted because it is almost there :)

Comment: Then your error message makes no sense.  Why do you _believe_ it's a `varchar`?  Can you not see the structure?

Comment: It is an INT and I converted it into a varchar like this: `SELECT TOP 10 CONVERT(DATETIME,
        SUBSTRING(CAST(date_period2 AS varchar(4)),1,4) + '-' 
      + SUBSTRING(CAST(date_period2 AS varchar(2)),5,2) + '-01')
FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[ASCCASHBLUE]`

Comment: Now I get this error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: Casting it to `VARCHAR(2)` will only take the two left-most digits.  Use `SUBSTRING(CAST(date_period2 AS varchar(6)),5,2)` instead.  Note that my answer would have been different from the start if I knew the column was an `int`

Comment: I totally agree, I am in the learning phase of SQL hence my answer was a little hazy :)

Comment: Now, The getting the business days would change a bit right? Because now I have the first day of the month?

Comment: Thank you. I put your query and part of my previous query together and got it to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date_period2 to a datetime data type with following logic.

Please change as per your need.

```
declare @i int
select @i = CONCAT('201305','01')
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),@i))
```

In `CONCAT('201305','01')` '01' will be constant, only '201305' will change.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error: `CONCAT` is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: It should work, its a SQL Server function. May be version issue. Try with simple concat using + sign.

Comment: So instead of 201304 should I just add my `date_period2` variable?

Comment: Try something like this, SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(8),date_period2+'01'))

Answer (score 1):

**201404 can converted into 04-2014**

```
declare @x VARCHAR(20)
SET @x = convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 126) 
select SUBSTRING(@x,6,CHARINDEX('-',@x)) +'-'+SUBSTRING(@x,0,CHARINDEX('-',@x))
```