# Oracle: How to convert a string into date format

Tags: string, oracle, date

Have done a lot of search before asking this question, like [How to convert a string into date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365671/how-to-convert-a-string-into-date-format), [How to convert a string into date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495504/how-to-convert-a-string-into-date), but still can't figure it out.

So, here's the question, how to convert these string dates into date in `Oracle`:

> "2016-08-15 10:45:30" (String type) -> 20160815 (Date type)
>
> "20160815104530" (String type) -> 20160815 (Date type)

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the time portions? Because, Oracle's DATE type does support date + time.

Comment: I should also mention that the posts you linked to are not for Oracle.  You can't expect to find Oracle-useful info in posts for SQL Server or Excel. And why not go to the source anyways? [Official TO_DATE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132)

Comment: I just want to get date, no time portions need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two things here:

The first is the conversion of a String data type, in Oracle `VARCHAR2` into a `DATE` data type.
The `DATE` data type has a precision of seconds, you can't change that. A `DATE` data type will always give you the date and time component, i.e year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds: [Oracle SQL Data Type Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020)

However, the second part of what you are asking is about how to format the date when retrieved. This is helpful when running reports, or other kinds of visual display of dates. For example, in the US you would most likely want your date columns appear in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` while everywhere else in the world you most likely want to stick with `DD/MM/YYYY`. Oracle lets you do that by telling it what [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG203) you want to use. You can set that parameter for each individual session as well as on database level, it is up to you (and your DBA) to decide where and when you want to set that. In your case you can apply this via the `ALTER SESSION` command:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('2016-08-15 10:45:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE(
----------
2016-08-15

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('20160815104530', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE(
----------
2016-08-15
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(substr(str1, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
select to_date(substr(str2, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: Thank you, but it shows up: `2016-08-15 00:00:00` when execute `select to_date(substr(str2, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD')`, how can I just get the date according to the format of `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: @triffic . .  Use `to_char()`.  In Oracle, the `date` type includes the time as well.